# python - How to resolve KeyError when pulling from a json dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, keyerror

I'm working on a project where I'm utilizing the Foursquare API to pull venue information from locations around Portland. I've been having an issue when trying to pull information from the json dictionary and structuring it into a dataframe using a custom function I wrote. For some reason, the function I wrote is flagging a KeyError on the 'groups' section in the dictionary, even though there are items in it and it is present in the dictionary. I had a hunch that the KeyError could be triggered due to some of the groups in the dictionary not having any items in them when.

ex: (look at the 'items' subgroup towards the bottom and you'll see there is an empty list. My function is looking for information in this subgroup, so maybe that's what is flagging the error,)

```
{'meta': {'code': 200, 'requestId': '5e4330219fcb92001bd8a847'},
 'response': {'warning': {'text': 'There aren\'t a lot of results for "(\'Bookstore\', \'Comic Shop\', \'Used Bookstore\', \'Library\')." Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area.'},
  'headerLocation': 'University Park',
  'headerFullLocation': 'University Park, Portland',
  'headerLocationGranularity': 'neighborhood',
  'query': 'bookstore comic shop used bookstore library',
  'totalResults': 0,
  'suggestedBounds': {'ne': {'lat': 45.5830000045, 'lng': -122.72538279609336},
   'sw': {'lat': 45.573999995499996, 'lng': -122.73821720390666}},
  'groups': [{'type': 'Recommended Places',
    'name': 'recommended',
    'items': []}]}}
```

compared to this, which would be what a "normal" dictionary from the API request would look like:

```
{'meta': {'code': 200, 'requestId': '5e4335769da7ee001b203b56'},
 'response': {'warning': {'text': 'There aren\'t a lot of results for "(\'Bookstore\', \'Comic Shop\', \'Used Bookstore\', \'Library\')." Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand the search area.'},
  'headerLocation': 'Cathedral Park',
  'headerFullLocation': 'Cathedral Park, Portland',
  'headerLocationGranularity': 'neighborhood',
  'query': 'bookstore comic shop used bookstore library',
  'totalResults': 2,
  'suggestedBounds': {'ne': {'lat': 45.5928000045, 'lng': -122.7515716757994},
   'sw': {'lat': 45.583799995499994, 'lng': -122.76440832420062}},
  'groups': [{'type': 'Recommended Places',
    'name': 'recommended',
    'items': [{'reasons': {'count': 0,
       'items': [{'summary': 'This spot is popular',
         'type': 'general',
         'reasonName': 'globalInteractionReason'}]},
      'venue': {'id': '5632a8dc498e5636877e4fa3',
       'name': 'Comic Cave PDX',
       'location': {'address': '1920 N. Kirkpatrick',
        'crossStreet': 'Denver',
        'lat': 45.59002437301252,
        'lng': -122.75552067488051,
        'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
          'lat': 45.59002437301252,
          'lng': -122.75552067488051}],
        'distance': 271,
        'postalCode': '97217',
        'cc': 'US',
        'city': 'Portland',
        'state': 'OR',
        'country': 'United States',
        'formattedAddress': ['1920 N. Kirkpatrick (Denver)',
         'Portland, OR 97217',
         'United States']},
       'categories': [{'id': '52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b18',
         'name': 'Comic Shop',
         'pluralName': 'Comic Shops',
         'shortName': 'Comic Shop',
         'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/comic_',
          'suffix': '.png'},
         'primary': True}],
       'photos': {'count': 0, 'groups': []}},
      'referralId': 'e-0-5632a8dc498e5636877e4fa3-0'},
     {'reasons': {'count': 0,
       'items': [{'summary': 'This spot is popular',
         'type': 'general',
         'reasonName': 'globalInteractionReason'}]},
      'venue': {'id': '5d617b8e228cfc0008fb1f9f',
       'name': 'Two Rivers Bookstore',
       'location': {'address': '8836 N Lombard St',
        'lat': 45.591434,
        'lng': -122.75648600000001,
        'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
          'lat': 45.591434,
          'lng': -122.75648600000001}],
        'distance': 368,
        'postalCode': '97203',
        'cc': 'US',
        'city': 'Portland',
        'state': 'OR',
        'country': 'United States',
        'formattedAddress': ['8836 N Lombard St',
         'Portland, OR 97203',
         'United States']},
       'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d114951735',
         'name': 'Bookstore',
         'pluralName': 'Bookstores',
         'shortName': 'Bookstore',
         'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/bookstore_',
          'suffix': '.png'},
         'primary': True}],
       'photos': {'count': 0, 'groups': []}},
      'referralId': 'e-0-5d617b8e228cfc0008fb1f9f-1'}]}]}}
```

I added an Except clause recently which allowed the function to execute, but when I used it every item was flagged as an exception (even the pulls that should have items in the dictionary). My code and the errors are below:

**My code:**

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, limit=500):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION,
            lat,
            lng,
            query, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)

        try:
        results = requests.get(url, "none").json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']


            venues_list.extend([(
                name, 
                lat, 
                lng, 
                v['venue']['name'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
                v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

        except KeyError:
            venues_list.extend([(
               name,
               lat,
               lng,
               np.nan,
               np.nan,
               np.nan,
               np.nan)]) 

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame(venues_list, columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category'])

    return(nearby_venues)
```

(As a side note, what is the 0 in the results pull above (['responses']['groups'][0]['items]) doing exactly? Borrowed this section of code from the course that I'm working on.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-66be6cf8c7d3> in <module>
      1 PDX_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=PDX_NeighDF['Neighborhood'],
      2                              latitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Latitude'],
----> 3                              longitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Longitude']
      4                              )
      5 

<ipython-input-15-dab42c6d540d> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, limit)
     15 
     16         #try:
---> 17         results = requests.get(url, "none").json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']
     18 
     19 

KeyError: 'groups'
```

This is the function trying to build the dataframe:

```
PDX_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=PDX_NeighDF['Neighborhood'],
                             latitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Latitude'],
                             longitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Longitude']
                             )

PDX_venues.head()

output: (structured in a pandas df normally)

    Neighborhood    Neighborhood Latitude   Neighborhood Longitude  Venue   Venue Latitude  Venue Longitude Venue Category
0   CATHEDRAL PARK  45.58830    -122.75799  NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   UNIVERSITY PARK 45.57850    -122.73180  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   PIEDMONT    45.56510    -122.66820  NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   WOODLAWN    45.56970    -122.65240  NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   ARBOR LODGE 45.57354    -122.69240  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I greatly appreciate any help! Let me know if you need any more info or background on the code and I'll be happy to provide more.

Comment: _For some reason, the function I wrote is flagging a KeyError on the 'groups' section in the dictionary, even though there are items in it and it is present in the dictionary. I had a hunch that the KeyError could be triggered due to some of the groups in the dictionary not having any items in them when._ The KeyError should not be caused by whether or not the list is empty. You need to break up the line `results = requests.get(url, "none").json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']`, and examine the result at each step.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options for this.

When accessing the dict you could use the `get` function on the dict. This function pulls the value but lets you set a default as well.

```
results = requests.get(url, "none").json().get('response', {})('groups', [])
```

Python does not have an equivalent for lists though, so in that case you're going to have to write some if statements to see if the list has elements to extract.

Another option is to add a lot more checks and to bail out sooner if the item doesn't exist.

```
jsonBlob = requests.get(url, "none").json()
if 'response' not in jsonBlob or 'groups' not in jsonBlob['response']:
    return False
```